# How to select the first paragraph in a div with a specific class (CSS 2)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a `<div>` containing many `<p>` elements and need to apply some style only to the first `<p>` inside every `<div>` with a **specific class (cnt)**.

*Please note this question may appear similar to others on SO, but the role I need should apply only for class `cnt`, which makes it different.*

```
//I use YUI 3 Reset and Grid:
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.0/build/cssfonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.0/build/cssgrids/grids.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <div class="cnt">
             <p>Number 1</p>
             <p>Number 2</p>
             <p>Number 3</p>
        </div>


            // I'm using this class without success!"
           .cnt p:first-child
            {
                background-color:Red;
            }

    // Other classes could create some conflict
    .cnt p
    {
        margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
    .cnt h2, .cnt h3, .cnt h4, .cnt h5, .cnt h6
    {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .cnt ul, .cnt ol
    {
        margin: 10px 0px 10px 30px;
    }
    .cnt ul > li
    {
        list-style-type: disc;
    }
    .cnt ol > li
    {
        list-style-type: decimal;
    }
    .cnt strong
    {
        font-weight:700;   
    }
    .cnt em
    {
        font-style:italic;
    }
    .cnt hr
    {
        border:0px;
        height:1px;
        background-color:#ddddda;
        margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
    .cnt del
    {
        text-decoration:line-through;
        color:Red;
    }
    .cnt blockquote 
    {   margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        border: 1px dashed #E6E6E6;
    }
    .cnt blockquote p
    {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

PS: I need it in `CSS 2` (neither the less CSS3 :first-of-type works great)

Comment: Just put the first such `p` element in its own class.

Comment: I cannot do it, I need another more comprehensive approach.

Comment: Hmm how isnt it working, http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/DA3rp/1/ just tried it there and it works fine.

Comment: I tried and it is working fine, too. Where are you calling the selector?

Comment: -1 Sorry, you need to provide a real code sample instead of one that you claim does not work but actually works.

Comment: You are probably right BoltClock but mistakes can happen to anyone. By the way new approach came up on my question so it still some how useful for other programmers, so please consider once again your down vote. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: @GibboK: If you edit with an accurate code sample I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock for your opportunity and suggestions, so I added a more accurate code sample. If you feel re-consider your down vote. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi BoltClock I post accurate code please have a look and remove down vote thanks!

Comment: No, your CSS selector should still select that first `p` in your HTML.

Comment: I see, I understand your point. Anyway thanks for still commenting. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your example should work fine

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/DA3rp/2/)**

Alternate method

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/DA3rp/)**

Try using the `first-of-type` selector.

```
.cnt p:first-of-type{
    background-color:Red;
}
```

It is a CSS3 selector and wont work on IE8 however.

Comment: is it CSS 3? It seems wokring right now but I would need fully compatible with Css2.

Comment: Any other alternatives? Thanks for your time on this!

Comment: @GibboK I tried `first-child` and it seems to work for me check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/DA3rp/2/

Comment: If you need a solution that works in IE7+, see Chris' answer, but use `~` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 5):

One thing that people always forgets about are adjacent selectors, that work (to some extent) in IE7+, try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="paragraph">
    <p>some paragraph</p>
    <p>some paragraph</p>
    <p>some paragraph</p>
    <p>some paragraph</p>
    <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    color:black;
}

.paragraph p {
    color:red;
}

.paragraph p + p {
    color:black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/AHHrF/

Comment: See my comment on Chris' answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a different method, not using :first-child.

http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/dp3vK/6/

It involves setting a style for all p tags (to get generic styling), then only where a p tag is after a p tag will more styles be affected. You can use this to your advantage, set ALL the p tags to have the style of the first tag, then overwrite for the others

Comment: This only works if every child is a `p`. You may get somewhere further using `.cnt p ~ p` in your second rule.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <p>Number 1</p>
  <p>Number 2</p>
  <p>Number 3</p>
</div>
```

Go to your css

```
.cnt p:first-of-type{
  /* Then give it style you want  */
}
```

Comment: You could put your css block in a code tag to help users.